# Android drawable resource id conflict?

Tags: android, resources, android-activity, zxing

I've set up the /android project of ZXing 1.7 as a library referenced 
by my main android app project. As a quick test / proof of concept, I 
have used the CaptureActivity, in the same manner as described here: 
http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcod...

Mostly, things work well, I can launch the CaptureActivity and receive 
the scanned data in my activity that launched it. However, I get some 
really strange behaviour, which I think may be related to resource IDs 
conflicting between my project and the /android ZXing project. This 
will take some explaining so please bear with me...

I launch the CaptureActivity with this code:

```
Button scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainmenu_btn_scan); 
scanBtn.setOnClickListener( 
    new View.OnClickListener() 
{ 
    public void onClick(View v) 
    { 
        Intent i = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
        i.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); 
        startActivityForResult(i, SCAN_CODE); 
    } 
});
```

`mainmenu_btn_scan` is defined in menu.xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mainmenu_view" style="@style/MainMenu" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <Button android:id="@+id/mainmenu_btn_scan" 
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_scan_drawable" 
                    style="@style/MainMenuButton" 
                    android:text="Scan"/>
    ... 
</LinearLayout>
```

btn_scan_drawable.xml is in /drawable, and is a drawable selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scan_btn_pressed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" /> 
    ...
</selector>
```

The stange problem is this: when I hold the phone in a *lanscape* 
orientation and launch the CaptureActivity, I see the scan_btn_pressed 
image stretched across the display, and another copy of it also 
stretched across the "Place a barcode inside the viewfinder rectangle 
text...". This only occurs when I launch the activity while holding 
the phone in *landscape* orientation.

I discovered that if I replace

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_scan_drawable"
```

with

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/scan_btn_pressed"
```

The problem goes away and everything works perfectly, but I want to get it working with the selector (and understand why the problem occurs). How can a drawable from my 
activity's UI mysteriously show up in another activity? I'm new to Android development, but I've been googling and working at this issue all day and I can't seem to find out why this would be happening apart from some vague references to resource ID conflicts in the android docs.

Note: I am using CaptureActivity as a rapid prototype / proof of concept only. I will implement my own activity leveraging the ZXIng library for the final app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems like the Android platform has a few wrinkles when using library projects. I noticed that the R class of my project and the R class of the ZXIng library project were conflicting all over the place e.g.

```
public static final class id {
    ...
    public static final int mainmenu_btn_scan=0x7f070028;
    ...
```

And in the library project's R class:

```
public static final class id {
    ...
    public static final int share_app_button=0x7f070028;
    ...
```

This explains how a UI element from my activity was being picked up by an activity in the library project. Android will give priority to resources ids in the main project.

This excellent article gave the solution: http://blog.blackmoonit.com/2010/12/android-sharing-resources-in-eclipse.html

In CaptureActivity (the activity I was calling in the library), I replaced

```
viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
```

With this

```
viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(
    getResources().getIdentifier("viewfinder_view", "id", getPackageName()) );
```

This fixed the issue, although I'll need to go through and replace all direct id references with getIndentifier() to ensure there aren't any other conflicts. Not an ideal solution. It feels like there ought to be some fairly straightforward extension to the aapt tool to ensure that the ids between R classes don't conflict.

See here for more info: http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/android-application-android-libraries-and-jar-libraries/

Comment: I think that's the long-way-round solution -- you can also just make sure to import the right R, or, use your.package.R.id.viewfinder_view to differentiate. This is more a question of Java imports. It also kind of highlights the issue in reusing a project that's not meant to be copied, not as a library project.

Comment: I don't think so, the real problem is that there are collisions in the ids in the R classes. com.somelib.R.share_app_button == com.myapp.R.mainmenu_btn_scan, the correct R file is being used, but due to the collisions and Android's resource priority rules, the library's R file ids end up referencing resources in my application.

Comment: @SeanOwen : the resource ID conflict occurs because multiple resources in different projects are being mapped to the same integer ID value. It doesn't matter if you qualify your Java code with package name or not - they map to the same value. When the Android runtime is given the integer ID value to look up for something, it did not have information to help it resolve the conflict, and therefore it can only follow the predefined resource priority rules, which in many cases turn up the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

use `project->clean..` to regenerate `R` Class