# Missing or Incorrect images and backgrounds randomly throughout app lifecycle

Tags: android, image, layout, tearing

I was hoping someone here might have an idea what causes this sort of behaviour:

Throughout my application, in seemingly random places and in random conditions I'm observing this strange UI issue. Images are on occasion being loaded black (with the correct bounds) or with the incorrect image source (again, with the correct bounds). This effects `ImageViews` and has effected `android:background` tags with references to colour resources.

My application relies on 6 library projects, it runs Native Code via a Service and Activities in the App use GlSurfaceViews (although, not all Activities which display the problem contain OpenGL components). The problem could I suppose be from any of these places or a combination of them through using large amounts of memory.

You can see this behaviour in the following screen shots:

- This is actually a 6 or so pixel wide column separator image which has been incorrectly drawn into my ImageView (the ImageView seems to have correctly sized itself).

  [image: Torn]
- When going out of the Application and then back in again (repeatedly) it instead appeared (and remained) like so:

  [image: Black]
- After a Force Clear and a Clear App Data it returned to the correct format:

  [image: This is the original:]

As you can also see the Magnifying Glass image next to it is displaying fine in each of these. The problems with these missing/incorrect images and backgrounds seems to happen randomly, throughout the application lifecycle, and I've been unable to find a way of reproducing it.

The layouts for these images are nothing special, I'm not doing anything funny during the rendering lifecycle (i'm not overriding `onDraw()` or `onMeasure()` or the like). The source of these images aren't being set dynamically but via the XML.

As you can see from the above example, it's not a build issue as it occurs between app lifecycles not between installs. It's also happening on different devices, Samsung 8.9, Acer Iconia Tab, Motarola XOOM,

It seems to me to be some sort of error with the reference table, could it perhaps have been nudged by my native code? Or is it an effect of me in some stages of the application using too much memory?

Here's the XML source for the above example:

```
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/browseProgressWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_compat_height"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/search_bar_width"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">       
        <EditText       android:id="@+id/browseFilter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"         
                        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_blue"
                        android:maxLength="30"/>
        <ImageView      android:id="@+id/clearSearch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_input_delete"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>                   
    <ImageView      android:id="@+id/browseFilterButton"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/actionbar_compat_height"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_compat_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minWidth="@dimen/actionbar_compat_height"/>         
</LinearLayout>
```

**A more full description of the code / layout surrounding another such occurrence I happened to get the screenshot for:**

I have a "Settings" `Activity` which restarts my app after saving new settings details. It does this by stopping a `Service`, calling a new `Activity` (the Splash Activity) and finishing itself:

```
   mConfiguration.save();
   mConfiguration = new Configuration(Configuration.getInstance());
   getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), NativeService.class));
   getActivity().finish();
   startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SplashActivity.class));
```

Most of the time (and on most devices) this works fine, the Splash Activity contains an image which loads correctly. Sometimes though on some devices the Splash Activity loads either an incorrect resource (what my testers refer as "an upside down Nike tick") or just a blank box (as seen below). Does anyone know why?

[image]

Here is the Layout for the Splash page, as you can see it's pretty simple, no surprises:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ContentBackgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/manager_android_400" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Theory tested and debunct:**

I've theorised that this could be a processor/memory issue where the Layout isn't being drawn fully before the Splash screen exits and moves onto the next Activity so I put in this piece of code:

```
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            image.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            moveToStartScreen.start();
        }
    });
```

The hope was the code above would make sure the Image is definitely loaded before moving onto the Start page but seems to have had no observable effect.

**Another Theory**

I was also wondering if this could be being caused by the R.id / R.colour / R.drawable resources some how being currupted in program execution? Does anyone know why *that* might happen.

Could my native code be running rampant on some memory addresses that Android isn't correctly allocating?

Has anybody noticed this before - or perhaps know why this behaviour occurs?

Comment: I've had issues with the wrong drawables showing up in library projects I was using, and since you reported the same thing I googled it and ended up with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724145/android-drawable-resource-id-conflict. Any help?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about how your native code interfaces with your app? Native code scribbling over something does seem most plausible to me.

Comment: @MattGibson The Native Code interfaces via JNI methods which fire callback/listener methods which UI component can register to receive. There is no direct data sending outside of JNI unless you consider Native code writing to the OpenGL context directly.

Comment: @Graeme I am curious to know if your problem is related to the one I had. I found a bypass for mine after countless debugging hours. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526275/custom-button-background-is-being-drawn-wrong-sometimes/16590387#16590387). If you have the opportunity to check my bypass let me know how it went.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graeme, I had almost the same problem and found out that it was a reported [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20283) of the android plattform. It was corrected in the 3.0 version I think. Which API are you compiling with? Try to build with the last available api and be sure to compile with JDK 1.6

If your problem is related to this bug, this should fix the problem.

Comment: It certainly presents differently than the one in the bug report (The missing images are throughout the app and therefore aren't the "first" image, although I can easily imagine this being a resource id collision and I've always suspected it to be an OS bug.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug isn't present on Honeycomb+ versions of the OS and so I'm hoping it's occurrences will grow less as more devices upgrade or become obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem of refresh, clean, and rebuild.
Images in your various drawable folders or resource id indices are out of sequence because they were either changed outside of the eclipse IDE (via external source control such as GIT, SVN or other edits) and not refreshed in the eclipse navigator. Or, the files may have been updated in a library project upon which your UI Activity depends.

I have found that although .java file dependencies are propagated throughout the system, this is not always the case for resources such as images and .xml files.

**The solution is fairly simple, clean everything, refresh all of your projects, and rebuild.** The stretched or black edges should be gone.

*Note: The predominant manifestation of this problem occurs when 9-patch images become treated like standard .png images. This means that they get stretched in a linear manner across the image instead of just at the edges. To me, this explains your 'Torn/Stretched' example. I have seen similar often. Another common manifestation is that text strings occasionally get displayed with the wrong resources!*

Comment: I had a similar issue where there was an error processing a 9-patch images but the maven build would _not_ process any image after the problem image but the whole build wouldn't fail, resulting in non-processed 9-patch images (which get built by the android SDK toolchain) getting included in the APK screwing up all the visuals.  The good thing was that it was maven and there was an error that was printed out to go find the problem.  Not sure if the Eclipse build can show you a log, but if it can/does, you might find it complaining about one resource throwing it all off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've had this issue for weeks going on for months across 10+ release builds and goodness knows how many 100's of debug builds.

Comment: Also, the images involved aren't 9-patches, also some of them aren't even images (they are links to colour resources). Also, clearing the data on the app and starting again fixes the problem meaning it can't be a build issue.