# Completely wrong ressource picked on some devices

Tags: android, listview

I have an odd issue with resources in my android app. I have a `ListView` where I set the background of elements depending on the state of the item. I'm doing this in the `getView`-Method of my adapter (`tv` is a `TextView`):

```
if (position == currentSelection - 1) {
    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_background_pressed);
    tv.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.my_white));
}
else {
    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_background);
    tv.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
}
```

`list_selector_background` contains different items depending on the state (pressed, focused, disabled, etc). Default state is `@color/transparent`. 
`list_selector_background_pressed` is a 9-patch-image and also used in `list_selector_background` as the pressed state.

On my Android 4.3 Emulator everything works fine. Same on my 4.3 Device. On my 2.2 Device (lowest supported API version) instead of the `list_selector_background` drawable a different image out of the drawable-hdpi gets displayed. The if-part works fine. The problem just occurs on the else part of the code.

I know about the issue with library projects and conflicting IDs discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724145/android-drawable-resource-id-conflicthttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724145/android-drawable-resource-id-conflict). My problem is similar but in a few details different. It **always** picks the wrong background for my `ListView` and it's always the same background. Sometimes it helps when I open a different activity first. Sometimes it doesn't. Clean didn't work. Complete uninstall and install again didn't work a

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

**Edit**

The complete source code of my getView methode:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setText(getItem(position));

    if (position == currentSelection - 1) {
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_background_pressed);
        tv.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.my_white));
    }
    else {
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_background);
        tv.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
    }

    return v;
}
```

`currentSelection` is an integer which is set by the view at a certain time. Then the item is supposed to look highlighted, which works fine on the emulator. It displays the image `icon_toolbox` of the drawable-hdpi folder. It's not part of the `list_selector_background` drawable, which looks like this:

```
<item android:state_window_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />

<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />

<item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
```

Comment: Which one is always the same background picked (paste the name of it). Also paste the code for the selector + the contents of the drawables (recources) folder.

Comment: Also, what is `position` and `currentSelection`, since you din't provide the code or the XML of the `listView`, then which element of it is the problematic one?

Comment: I updated my question. listView is just a simple ListView whicht covers the whole screen.

Comment: First remark - I don't see `list_selector_background_pressed` used anywhere in the selctor, even thout you said so (nevermind this). Second, I guess that `icon_toolbox` is the image you don't have in the selector (if yes, then where is this image situated? - That's why I needed to look at the drawables folder). Third - I see you use `android.R.id.text1`, but you should use instead the `R.id.text1`, because that's your actual XML (which I too wanted to take a look at). Please respond to those 3 remarks. Thanks

Comment: 1.) You are right. It is used in list_selector_background_transition
2.) correct. The icon is also a drawable with images for 3 different states and is used as an icon which onClick opens the activity with the ListView we're talking about. If I replace the icon with a different one, it works, wtf?? The drawable folders contain about 250 files.... Bit much to post here...
3.) the xml I use is android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. That's why I am using android.R.id.text1

Comment: I think that you have interfering methods, which both influence the `TextView`. One being this `onClick` you're apeaking about and the second being the state selector, from the code above. The `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is a default one, as far as I know, thus all the android.R% things, which are sometimes replaced, when you have a problem in the R.java file, that's why it was suspicious for me (if it suits your need, then ok). But if you defined a XML (manually) for the textView, then it is defined in the R.java, not in android.R ...

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction! I used a custom layout now (which is the same as android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) and now it works. I would understand this if the issue would have been the same after changing the icon which starts the activity. But it worked with a different one. Anyway, thanks for your help. Post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments section:

I think that you have interfering methods, which both influence the `TextView` - the one being this `onClick` you're speaking about and the second being the state selector, from the code above.
The `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is a default one, as far as I know, thus all the `android.R%` things, which are sometimes replaced, when you have a problem in the `R.java` file, that's why it was suspicious for me (if it suits your need, then ok).

But if you defined a `XML` (manually) for the `TextView`, then it is defined in the `R.java`, not in `android.R` ...